# Objectify - Add @Id to any class

Tags: java, objectify

I have many custom object classes used by both a server (GAE) and client (Android) in a RESTful system. For ease of maintainability, the code for these objects is common between server and client.

In order to make these objects storable with Objectify on the server side, one field must be annotated @Id. However, I can't do this in each object class without importing javax.persistence on the client (or creating separate client/server copies of the code) (or, for every object, creating a "StorableX extends X" with cloning).

Is it possible to use an adapter or wrapper pattern to dynamically make any object storable via Objectify? What is the best practice for this?

Thanks,
--John

Answer (score 0):

There is normally no problem using an annotated class without the annotation interface being present in the classpath, even if the annotation is a runtime one. Of course, if the class byte-code is instrumented or if some class tries using the annotation at runtime, it's another matter.

Comment: "Id cannot be resolved to a type" prevents building and running the client.

Comment: Add the javax.persistence jar to build the annotated classes, but don't include it in the classpath of the client at runtime. If these classes are common to server and client, they should be compiled once for both tiers, and not twice.

Comment: If javax.persistence.Id is imported to the common annotated class X, it can be built successfully and added to the classpath of server and client. However, when the client attempts to instantiate an object of type X, it can't handle "import javax.persistence.Id;"

Comment: For the record, I'm using Eclipse. The common project is not listed as a Project Reference for server or client, it is not listed as a project on the build path of the server or client, and does not share src via linking.

Comment: import is not a runtime statement. It's a compile-time thing. You should be able to use your annotated class without the ID annotation being in the classpath. Did you try it? Did you have any error?

Comment: I am trying to understand your question here. Why would you need to have an @Id annotation for a client class? If you say the class is being shared between the client and the server, then isnt it fine? In that case I would have a Main `Entity` class with @Entity and all subclases to be persisted with @EntitySubclass annotation